# Boolean Expression Simplification Error. Results not matching with the given results.

Tags: boolean-algebra

I was simplifying the expression:

(K.(K.(J+L))')+(K'.(K.(J+L)))

=(K.(K'+(J+L)'))+(K.K'.(J+L))

=(1+K.(J+L)')+(J+L)

=(1+K.(J'.L'))+(J+L)

=1+K.J'.L'+J+L

However, when I was evaluating this Simplified expression using the truth table, the result did not come as expected.

For J=K=L=1, the result is:

1+(1)(0)(0)+1+1=1

While the result is supposed to be 0.

Anything's wrong with my calculations?

Comment: Please, format your questions properly using MathJax. Anyway, aren't you aware that $1+X=1$, for whatever $X$? (In your case $X=KJ'L'+J+L$). Perhaps there's nothing wrong with your simplification...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the second row: $K.K´=0,$ not $1.$